# Inverse of 'concat': transforming a flattened list into a nested list

Tags: haskell

Given a flattened list in Haskell:

```
['a', 'b','c','d']
```

how can I change it to:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
singleton x = [x]
f = map singleton
```

Comment: How about `f = map (: [])`?

Comment: @Claudio Even better.

Comment: or `f = map return` :-)

Comment: or (this is 2016!) `f = map pure` :-)

Answer (score 8):

One way to describe what you want to do is to take each element in your list and wrap it, individually, with another list. Or, you'd like to perform the operation `'a' ---> ['a']` to each element of the list.

Whenever you're speaking about turning "each element of the list, individually, into something else" you're talking about a `map` [0] and so we'll write this function a bit like

```
example :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
example cs = map _ cs
```

Where the `_` is the function `'a' ---> ['a']`. This function can be written as an explicit anonymous function, though

```
example :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
example cs = map (\c -> [c]) cs
```

And this will achieve what we need!

But we can go a little further. First, in Haskell you're allowed to *drop* the last argument applied if it's the same as the last input argument. Or, more concretely, we can also write `example` as

```
example :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
example = map (\c -> [c])
```

by simply deleting the `cs` in both the argument list and as an argument to `map`. Second, we can take note that `example`'s type is weaker than it could be. A better way of writing it is certainly

```
example :: [a] -> [[a]]
example = map (\c -> [c])
```

which reflects the fact that we didn't use anything specific to `Char` on the inside.

[0] Or, more generally, an `fmap`

Answer (score 6):

Well, Ting already answered, but I feel compelled to introduce you to the monkey operator `(:[])`

You can use this in place of `singleton`.

```
map (:[]) ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```